# Aligned partitioning of 2TB disk with Linux fdisk

Tags: linux, fdisk, partition-alignment

Is there a way to create a single 2TB partition, which is 4096-byte-sector aligned, on a disk using the standard Linux fdisk (I have tried version 2.17.2)?

I've tried the following things and ran into the described error:

- If I simply use the `-u` flag, it sets the cluster size to one sector of 512 byte. Then, the partition would have to be 3,906,250,000 clusters long and fdisk truncates this number to 2,147,483,647 (2^31-1).
- If I use `-b 4096`, it allows me to create the partition just fine (with length 488,281,506 sectors), but if I check the size of the resulting partition using `blockdev --getsize64`, it shows that the partition is only 250GB big, i.e. it is still using a sector size of 512.
- If I try to set the sector and head count using `-S 64 -H 32`, for example, then it always sets the sector count back to 63, which doesn't divide evenly into 4096 (I know, 32 dividing evenly by 8 is technically enough, but - call me perfectionist - I'd really like to have the partition start at sector 2048 (1MB aligned), as I read is the recommended setting these days.

Is there some combination of parameters that I can pass to fdisk, that will allow me to create a partition that starts at 1MB (sector 2048 [256] for 512-[4096-]byte sectors) and is exactly 2TB long (3,906,250,000 [488,281,506] sectors for 512-[4096-]byte sectors)?

(I read that I can just use gparted and have it change the drive to GPT partitioning, but I'd really like to know if there is a way to do it with standard fdisk and an MBR partition. I don't see a reason why MBR partitions shouldn't allow for this...)

Comment: What OS/distribution/kernel/version?

Comment: @ewwhite Not sure it matters too much for the question, but here you go: Debian Squeeze 6.0.7, stock kernel 2.6.32-5-686, fdisk 2.17.2...

Comment: It matters because partition alignment along sectors is the default on newer Linux distributions.

Comment: @ewwhite Is that something that depends on more than just the version of fdisk I'm using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Newer versions of fdisk (e.g. v2.20.1) do not have the issue of truncating the cluster number as described in the question any more. Therefore, one can now simply use

```
fdisk -c /dev/sdX
```

to create a partition starting at 2048 and ending at 3906252047 to create the desired layout.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

I found one way to do it:

```
fdisk -S 16 -H 1 -c /dev/sdX
```

Then, I can create a partition that starts at 129 and ends at 244,140,753.

Now, if I do `fdisk -l -u /dev/sdX`, I will get:

```
Disk /dev/sdX: 2000.4 GB, 2000365289472 bytes
1 heads, 16 sectors/track, 244185216 cylinders, total 3906963456 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xee3e796d

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdX1            2048  3906252047  1953125000   fd  Linux raid autodetect
```

and `blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sdX1` gives me exactly 2,000,000,000,000.

Now the big question: Does anyone see a problem with the -S 16 -H 1? :)

Comment: As long as you're not booting from it, it just might work, but as long as the drive reports that it has 512/512 byte sectors, the BIOS will never figure out this partition.

Comment: @DerfK, fortunately, `grub` does not use the CHS addressing method that has been depreciated for 15+ years now, so it won't matter unless you try to install Windows.

Answer (score 5):

Use `parted` instead of `fdisk`.  It will take care of the alignment automatically and doesn't have this bug you seem to have discovered in `fdisk`.  Also, there is no such thing as clusters.  It is either sectors, or cylinders, which are depreciated junk left over from the early '90s.

Answer (score 1):

There's a reason why GPT exists, and you appear to have discovered it. There's no value in pushing a square peg through a round hole.

Comment: Does the standard linux fdisk also support GPT or will I have to use a different tool?

Comment: Yes, you should be using a different tool. `fdisk` isn't really useful on disks >= 2TB, and there are much better tools now anyway.

Comment: You want to use gdisk or parted.